# Should we run iPhone application in xcode 5 with ios simulator 7?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have generated a build in Xcode 4.6 and tested it in iPhone 5 device with iOS 7.4  and its working fine and I was not getting any issues such as status bar missing, `UIButton` background missing etc. But if I run the same code in Xcode 5 with iOS simulator7 then I was getting issues such as status bar missed, background of UIButton missed and I couldn't able to change the table view back ground color. So finally should I run my code in Xcode 5 with iOS simulator 7 and fix all the issues? OR can I directly push this app in to App Store with out checking it in Xcode 5. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can submit the app compiled with Xcode 4.x to the app store. But it would be good if you fix all the issues with Xcode 5 and then submit it.

Comment: I faced the same issue.. the XIB's build on xCode 4.x.x look differently (all views lost there x y positions and goes in negative values )on Xcode 5 on opening seems like xCode5 tries to convert the older XIBs to newer 1.. 1 solution is to change the xibs setting to openswith 4.x but better if you change your XIB to newer xCode5 compatible and fix the UI issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Xcode 4.6 the base SDK is for iOS6. So if you build an application on Xcode 4.6 it will run iOS 7 but it will not be able to use the API's provided by Apple for iOS7. It will a iOS6 app running on iOS7 like many other apps do.

In Xcode 5.0 the base SDK is for iOS7. This means that you can use the latest APIs provided for iOS7. You are getting these errors when building in Xcode 5.0 because those APIs might not be supported in the new iOS7 SDK.

What I mean to say is that if you want your app to be a native iOS7 app then you need to build it on Xcode 5. Building on Xcode 5 will allow your app to feel like an iOS7 app. Though you will face a lot of errors as a lot of iOS6 APIs have been deprecated in iOS7.

If you want to support both iOS6 and iOS7 I suggest you build it on Xcode 5. Again you will have to keep in mind that some iOS7 API's are not available for iOS6 therefore you will have to keep a check on that.

To get a better idea I suppose you should have a look at this document.
[iOS7 transition guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/)

Thank You.

Comment: Thank you for a quick response.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely build and test in Xcode 5, why run the risk of shipping a bad product? For me you must properly test this in Xcode 5, on all deployment intended devices and the simulator.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the [iOS 7 UI Transition Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/Bars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH8-SW1) to fix all the issues you have in XCode 5 and then submit the app to the store.